# Uploading Image to Firebase and Getting Reference

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I've been trying to learn Firebase for an Instagram-type app I'm trying to create. I have been unable to follow some of the various resources online and needed assistance. Currently I have uploaded an image to Firebase through the console/website. My question is how do I obtain a reference to the image and how do I implement that reference into my Xcode project? I have already installed Cocoapods and Alamofire; I have also installed Firebase successfully through the instructions on the website and added code to the ViewController as follows:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase


class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var ref: DatabaseReference!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        ref = Database.database().reference()

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're uploading the images in the Firebase console, they're in Cloud Storage for Firebase, and not in the database.

To learn how to access them, read the Firebase [documentation for storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/start), including the section on [creating a reference to a file](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/create-reference), and [downloading files](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/download-files).

Comment: For that text in the 'creating a reference to a file' link, where do I put those references? Should I put that in the ViewController file?

Comment: Put it in the same place where you download the file. Storage references are simple paths to the files in Cloud Storage, and are quite cheap to build and keep.